# Laravel save() method returning true but not updating records

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I am using Eloquent to update my table Opportunity,

Opportunity Model

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Opportunity extends Model {

protected $primaryKey = 'OpportunityID';

protected $table = 'opportunitys';
// relationships
public function csfs()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Csf', 'opportunityID');
}

public function benefits()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Benefit', 'opportunityID');
}

public function risks()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Risk', 'opportunityID');
}

public function projects()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Project', 'projectID');
}

public static function createNewOpportunity($input, $projectID)
{
    $opportunity = new Opportunity;
    $opportunity->value = $input['value'];
    $opportunity->margin = $input['margin'];
    $opportunity->duration = $input['duration'];
    $opportunity->tender_type = $input['tender_type'];
    $opportunity->likelihood_of_success = $input['likelihood_of_success'];
    $opportunity->scope_of_work = $input['scope_of_work'];
    $opportunity->deliverables = $input['deliverables'];
    $opportunity->projectID = $projectID;
    $opportunity->high_level_background = $input['high_level_background'];
    if($opportunity->save())
        {
            Opportunity::leadSalesOppComplete($projectID);
            return true;
        };

}

public static function leadSalesOppComplete($projectID)
{
    $task = Lead::where('projectID', '=', $projectID)->first();
    $task->sales_opp = true;
    return $task->save();
}
```

}

```
public function updateOpportunity(Request $request, $id) {
```

I get the id and find the opportunity.

```
$something = Opportunity::find($id);
```

I have died and dumped this and I get this

```
Opportunity {#259 ▼
 #primaryKey: "OpportunityID"
#table: "opportunitys"
#connection: null
#perPage: 15
+incrementing: true
+timestamps: true
#attributes: array:12 [▼
"opportunityID" => 11
"value" => 0
"margin" => 0
"tender_type" => ""
"likelihood_of_success" => 0
"high_level_background" => ""
"scope_of_work" => ""
"deliverables" => ""
"duration" => ""
"projectID" => 6
"created_at" => "2015-03-11 17:45:47"
"updated_at" => "2015-03-11 17:45:47"
 ]
  #original: array:12 [▶]
#relations: []
#hidden: []
#visible: []
#appends: []
#fillable: []
#guarded: array:1 [▶]
#dates: []
#casts: []
#touches: []
#observables: []
#with: []
#morphClass: null
+exists: true
}
```

Which is correct. I then update these with

```
    $something->margin = $request['margin'];
    $something->duration = $request['duration'];
    $something->tender_type = $request['tender_type'];
    $something->likelihood_of_success = $request['likelihood_of_success'];
    $something->scope_of_work = $request['scope_of_work'];
    $something->deliverables = $request['deliverables'];
    $something->high_level_background = $request['high_level_background'];
```

Now if I die and dump I get

```
Opportunity {#259 ▼
#primaryKey: "OpportunityID"
#table: "opportunitys"
#connection: null
#perPage: 15
+incrementing: true
+timestamps: true
#attributes: array:12 [▼
"opportunityID" => 11
"value" => "25000"
"margin" => "0"
"tender_type" => "Proposal"
"likelihood_of_success" => "0"
"high_level_background" => ""
"scope_of_work" => ""
"deliverables" => ""
"duration" => ""
"projectID" => 6
"created_at" => "2015-03-11 17:45:47"
"updated_at" => "2015-03-11 17:45:47"
]
#original: array:12 [▼
  "opportunityID" => 11
  "value" => 0
  "margin" => 0
  "tender_type" => ""
  "likelihood_of_success" => 0
  "high_level_background" => ""
  "scope_of_work" => ""
  "deliverables" => ""
  "duration" => ""
  "projectID" => 6
  "created_at" => "2015-03-11 17:45:47"
  "updated_at" => "2015-03-11 17:45:47"
]
#relations: []
#hidden: []
#visible: []
#appends: []
#fillable: []
#guarded: array:1 [▶]
#dates: []
#casts: []
#touches: []
#observables: []
#with: []
#morphClass: null
+exists: true
}
```

I only changed the value which shows the change.

I now run

```
$something->save();
```

It returns true when I die and dump it.

But no records are changed in the database.

Any ideas?

two images from tinker

[image: Using Tinker to update]

[image: Using Tinker to update part 2]

[image: Var_dump after save]

Comment: What is the array $request? Any values in it?

Comment: In laravel-5 you use the Request class on all posts, its similar to using the old Input in laravel 4.2

Comment: If it is the injected instance of Request,  try get the value by calling input() instead, like $request->input('margin').

Comment: Thanks, but the values are working from the request array. The 2500 that is entered in the form, is added to the collection from the $request['value']. This issue is when the data is changed, and then the save method is used. It isn't updating the database even though it is returning true

Comment: How do you check that the record is not changed in the database?

Comment: That's tricky. But I think the problem is related to you dd() the save(). I suspect dd() simply stops the php script from execution. How about not interrupting it saves, and you check the database directly?

Comment: @Anatoliy  Well I first noticed it hadn't changed when the form model binding didn't pull through the new data. I looked in PHPMYADMIN and the value is still 0. Its really strange, as I can create new records.

Comment: @Carter I only use the DD for diagnosing purposes as I'm trying to find the route of the problem. When the save completes it returns to a different dashboard.

Comment: Very interesting. Maybe there is some DB transaction in progress when you are trying to update the record? Also, can you try to update the record from `php artisan tinker`?

Comment: I have loaded tinker up, but not sure how to run the command in tinker. Never used it

Comment: Just type what you would type in the controller: find a model, assign new value to a field then save it.

Comment: @Carter Okay, I have done that. I type $opportunity = Opportunity::find(11); and I get calls Opportunity not found. It does exist though.

Comment: Okay it's name spaced so I typed App\Opportunity and it worked. bare with me sorry

Comment: Maybe you should namespace the model because by default Laravel 5 declares models under App namespace.

Comment: Okay well, I executed the commands in tinker and the save returned true. It still didn't update my database

Comment: I have added the screenshots

Comment: Are you sure that you look at the correct database? Maybe it's a wrong URL in browser where PHPMyAdmin is opened or wrong DB name? Also, run please `var_dump(App\Oportunity::find(11))` after save.

Comment: Okay will do that for you now. I have just ran an update on a different model in that function and it updates perfectly. A bit of relief, as it seems to be only this model.

Comment: Added the screenshot

Comment: Type of the `value` field is `string(1)`. Try to save `5`, for example: `$opp->value = "5"; $opp->save()`

Comment: Okay, I've done that, and still no save. The only reason value is now a string is that I changed the structure in the database, to string from int to, check that it was communicating with the right one, and two it wasn't a datatype issue.

Comment: Hi guys I have solved the issue, Its really strange actually as I am able to add using this model. The ID that was declared in the Opportunity class was protected $primaryKey = "OpportunityID"; and the key should be opportunityID. What I don't understand is why I am able to save with this mistake and retrieve the model

Comment: Could this be a bug in Eloquent?

Comment: Feel free to add the answer, and take some brownie points, I really appreciate the help

Comment: Don't worry about points. I'm not sure about a bug, but I think you can ask about it in the #laravel-dev conf in IRC.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This line in the Opportunity model fixed the issue.

```
Protected $primaryKey = "opportunityID";
```

Although it is difficult to understand why it was still possible to retrieve the data and create a new record.

Comment: It feels like it has something to do with the encoding of your database/table. The ```save()``` method uses ```where``` from the query builder of Laravel to create the query with the properties of your object. So this is not really Laravel in the end, it's only making a query with the keys you've set. Now your table encoding can change things, ```utf8_general_ci``` is generally recommanded to dodge this kind of problem.

Answer (score 3):

I had a very similar issue and this post lead me to a solution. I too was overriding a `primaryKey`.

Environment:

- PHP 7.1
- Lumen 5.3 (obviously Eloquent enabled)
- Oracle 12 (using https://github.com/yajra/laravel-oci8)

`SELECT` and `INSERT` operations work with `protected $primaryKey = 'USER_ID';`, however, `UPDATE` operations did not work even though `save()` returned `true`.

After finding this post I changed case. `protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';`, Whammy, all three operations work! I wish I had a more solid explanation why this works. When I created the table I clearly used upper `USER_ID VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) NOT NULL`.

Comment: That's solve my issue! But didn't know what the heck is going on on my code!!! 

Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question in the title:

```
$user = \App\User::find(1);
$boolean = $user->save();
```

This will return true. Save always returns true, unless update or save did not succeed (because user_id is not found or something like this). Its not checked if an attribute has been changed. To see if an attribute has been changed see [Laravel check if updateOrCreate performed update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45702409/laravel-check-if-updateorcreate-performed-update/49350664#49350664)

Here is a bit of a Laravel eloquent Model.php :

```
    // If the model already exists in the database we can just update our record
    // that is already in this database using the current IDs in this "where"
    // clause to only update this model. Otherwise, we'll just insert them.
    if ($this->exists) {
      $saved = $this->isDirty() ?
         $this->performUpdate($query) : true;
    }


    // ...

    return $saved;
```

`isDirty()` is true if model attribute has been changed and not saved. So if `isDirty()` is false, model will be not updated and return true.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue with **Laravel 5.4** and **MySQL**. My original code was:

```
$attach = new Attachments ;
$attach->site_id = ($type == 'site' ? $typeId : null) ;
...
```

By adding a null primary id, `save()` behaves as expected.

```
$attach = new Attachments ;
$attach->id = null ;
$attach->site_id = ($type == 'site' ? $typeId : null) ;
...
```