# Laravel: Check with Observer if Column was Changed on Update

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I am using an [Observer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#observers) to watch if a user was updated.

Whenever a user is `updated` I would like to check if his `email` has been changed.

Is something like this possible?

```
class UserObserver
{


    /**
     * Listen to the User created event.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @return void
     */
    public function updating(User $user)
    {
      // if($user->hasChangedEmailInThisUpdate()) ?
    }

}
```

Comment: You mean the [`isDirty`](https://laravel.com/api/master/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_isDirty) method? There's also `wasChanged`.

Comment: @tadman yes! Thats what I was looking for. And is that compatible with the observer? I think updating is called after assigning changes to `user` but before storing it, right?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure of the details so you may need to experiment here. Dirty tracking is a common feature of many ORMs, Eloquent included.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Edit: Credits to https://stackoverflow.com/a/54307753/2311074 for `getOriginal`

As `tadman` already said in the comments, the method `isDirty` does the trick:

```
class UserObserver
{


    /**
     * Listen to the User updating event.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @return void
     */
    public function updating(User $user)
    {
      if($user->isDirty('email')){
        // email has changed
        $new_email = $user->email; 
        $old_email = $user->getOriginal('email');
      }
    }

}
```

If you want to know the difference between `isDirty` and `wasChanged`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/49350664/2311074

Comment: Unnecessary to transfer the model from the database again, see my answer for an updated version

Comment: relevant [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#examining-attribute-changes)

Comment: Shouldn't the function now be called `updated`?

Answer (score 21):

You don't have to get the user again from the database. The following should work:

```
public function updating(User $user)
{
  if($user->isDirty('email')){
    // email has changed
    $new_email = $user->email; 
    $old_email = $user->getOriginal('email'); 
  }
}
```

Comment: I upvoted your comment on the accepted answer but downvoted this since it's now a duplicate

Comment: @aowie1 That answer was updated after I commented on it :’(

Comment: I upvoted your answer because I don't think it deserves downvotes. However, I think its common practice on SO to edit minor improvements to an answer from comments. I would guess using `getOriginal` instead of `find` is just a minor improvement, because both work, and the main part about the answer is how to find if a model was changed: And that is the `isDirty` method. Maybe in this case it would be better if you had made an request by editing my question and changed the line. That would also give you credits.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using the `updating` event, You should use the `updated` model event to compare the column changes against the original. Please have a look at the below code.

AppServiceProvider.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        User::updated(function($user){
            $changes = array_diff($user->getOriginal(), $user->getAttributes());
            if(array_key_exists('email',$changes)){
                /* do your things. */
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Explanation:

- Once you get the difference then you need to use `array_key_exists` to check whether the email field got updated or not.

Comment: There is a shortcut for the same check whether a field has been updated: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#examining-attribute-changes
So you could instead use `if($user->wasChanged('email'))` ^^

Comment: @D.Petrov correct but if you have to capture multiple fields then you need to write for each column right so this is the efficient way to handle multiple column data.

Answer (score 3):

A little late to the party, but might be helpful for future devs seeking a similar solution.

I recommend using the package **[Laravel Attribute Observer](https://github.com/alexstewartja/laravel-attribute-observer)**, as an alternative to polluting your Service Providers or filling your Observers with `isDirty()` and `wasChanged()` boilerplate.

So your use case would look like this:

```php
class UserObserver
{


    /**
     * Handle changes to the "email" field of User on "updating" events.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @param string $newValue The current value of the field
     * @param string $oldValue The previous value of the field
     * @return void
     */
    public function onEmailUpdating(User $user, string $newValue, string $oldValue)
    {
      // Your logic goes here...
    }

}
```

**[Laravel Attribute Observer](https://github.com/alexstewartja/laravel-attribute-observer)** is especially useful when you have a lot of attributes to observe on one or more models.

*Disclaimer: I am the author of **[Laravel Attribute Observer](https://github.com/alexstewartja/laravel-attribute-observer)**. If it saves you some development time, consider buying me a coffee.*

Comment: Nice idea and well made, this should be included in Laravel by default!