# Laravel 5.6 - get changed values after updateOrCreate

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I have used laravel 5.6 and used the `updateOrCreate` model to add or update some data.
But I need to get all the values which changed

```
$q=Userssub::updateOrCreate(
    ['userid' => $uid  ],
    ['model'  => $model]
);
```

and the result shows like in this image

[image: screen shot of image]

How can I get the changes array?
I tried to get it with

```
$u->changes
```

and

```
$u->changes->toarray()
```

but both return null.
What can I do to get the changed values?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Eloquent models have two protected arrays, `$original` and `$changes`, which contain the attributes as they were when fetched from storage and the attrbirutes which have been modified, respectively.

So you can use `getOriginal()` and `getChanges()` and compare the differences.

```
$model = Model::createOrUpdate([...]);

// wasRecentlyCreated is a boolean indicating if the model was inserted during the current request lifecycle.
if (!$model->wasRecentlyCreated) {
   $changes = $model->getChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 18):

This creates an array which will contain the original attribute value and what it was changed to:

```
if (!$model->wasRecentlyCreated) {
    $original = $model->getOriginal();
    $changes = [];

    foreach ($model->getChanges() as $key => $value) {
        $changes[$key] = [
            'original' => $original[$key],
            'changes' => $value,
        ];
    }
}
```

e.g.

```
(
    [first_name] => [
        [original] => Kevinn
        [changes] => Kevin
    ]
    [website] => [
        [original] => google.com
        [changes] => google.ca
    ]
)
```